# Hide Master View Controller in UISplitView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got a bar button item on the navigation bar in my master view controller that appears when using a device in portrait. I want to be able to tap that item and hide the master controller even if a selection isn't made from the master controller table view. I can't seem to find any way of doing this. How can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Call `UISplitViewController showDetailViewController:sender:`

If you cannot, I think you need to implement:

`- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController
  ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController`

and return `NO` when you want to show the detail view.

EDIT: Actually -- I just looked at one of my projects.  Implementing that delegate is for when you are doing things like rotating an iPad in split screen (and it's separating/collapsing automatically)

For my project, I keep track of the last detailVC and use that to call `showDetailViewController:sender:`

Comment: The issue with that is I need to know which view controller to show. I load different view controllers depending on which row is selected so ideally the last one shown would be the one displayed.

Comment: You need to implement the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` methods (updating answer)

Comment: How are you keeping track of the last detailVC?

Comment: I subclassed the UISplitViewController